# enabling word-wrap in gitk for commit message display on a Mac

Tags: gitk

I have searched twice now and explored heavily and I concede. I can't find a working answer, to a simple dang problem! :(

**Problem**

gitk comments on my Mac are not word wrapped and overflow off the screen

**Example Illustration**

The bottom left window has the commit message overflow out the window ('On add_nscoding: this...')

[image]

**Question**

How do you enable word-wrap in the commit description & comment window on a Mac?

**Potential Solution**

'*wrapcomment*' is described of ~/.gitk here - http://marc.info/?l=git&m=114770603010712&w=2. But I could not find where this is!

Answer (score 4):

> 'wrapcomment' is described of ~/.gitk here - http://marc.info/?l=git&m=114770603010712&w=2. But I could not find where this is!

Find your `gitk` configuration file. On Linux, it can be at `~/.config/git/gitk` or `~/.gitk`. On Windows, it's at `%USERPROFILE%/.gitk`. I'm not sure where it would be on OS X, but probably along those lines.

This is a regular text file. There, change the line that starts with `set wrapcomment` to be `set wrapcomment word`. Save the file, restart gitk, and it should now word-wrap commit messages.